# Azure Data Factory: Results from query are not being passed into a stored procedure properly

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I am running a simple query lookup and I am expecting (and getting) 3 integer values (5, 35, 45). However, when I am referencing the lookup activity (syntax: @activity('Get_Batch_Schedule').output.value), I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot create Sql Source. Please double check the connection string,
> stored procedure are set with correct format. Error: The value of the
> property 'Value' is invalid for the stored procedure parameter
> 'batch_id'.

I am expecting the stored procedure to pick up the values and process the integers without a hitch, but it seems like the expected format is different than what the query is defaulting to.

Steps I have tried:

- Changing the expected parameter to string
- Cast the value in my query to an int explicitly
- Try every other input value possible

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue in my environment with sample data. I executed query to retrieve data from sql table in look up activity.
Query:

```
SELECT Age FROM student
```

I retrieved below data:

[image]

I am having below stored procedure in my database:

```
CREATE  PROC InsertValues(
  @Age int
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT  INTO  data  VALUES (@Age)
END
```

I called above stored procedure with stored procedure activity. I called Look up activity values by entering below dynamic content:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Age
```

[image]

I executed the pipeline, but I got below error:

[image]

By mistaken I selected datetime data type instead of int that's why I got above error. I changed the data type of variable to int.

It executed successfully without any error.

[image]

Once check the variables data types in stored procedures. You may resolve the issue.

Comment: Everything I did looked the same however, I did notice one key change. I noticed that your dynamic content lookup was different than the default that Microsoft gives. I was previously entering the following:

@activity('Get_Batch_Schedule').output.value

However, when I tried your method of indexing the array with [0].age, that worked for the stored procedure. 

But, I am attempting to loop through all of my values that I am returning with a foreach loop, do you have any idea what the syntax should be to achieve that as [0] will only process 1 value?

Thanks.